# LWC Lightning Datatable - Highlight Cell Dynamically

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable

I am trying to highlight a cell dynamically. I have used this link however I get an error.

Link: https://www.salesforcetroop.com/datatable_styling_in_lwc

HTML:

```
<lightning-datatable data={data} columns={columns} key-field="id" selected-rows={selectedRows}
                    onrowselection={handleSelectedRow}>
                </lightning-datatable>
```

JS:

```
const columns = [
    {
        label: 'EVENT REGISTRATION FIELD NAME', fieldName: 'eventregistrationfieldname', type: 'text',
        cellAttributes: { class: { fieldName: 'accountColor' } }
    },
    { label: 'SALESFORCE DATA', fieldName: 'salesforcedata', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'EVENT REGISTRATION DATA', fieldName: 'eventregistrationdata', type: 'text' }
];


GetData(){
    //call apex...
    let data = [];
    data.push({
                id: key,
                objectId: eventRegData[key].objectId,
                eventregistrationfieldname: eventRegData[key].label,
                salesforcedata: eventRegData[key].sfData,
                eventregistrationdata: eventRegData[key].regData,
                isSelected: eventRegData[key].isSelected,
                "accountColor": "datatable-orange" //does not work
            });
    this.data = registrationData;
}
```

CSS:

```
.datatable-orange {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #e06000;
}
```

Error I receive:

```
Error: [LWC error]: Dynamically setting the "stylesheets" property on a template function is deprecated and may be removed in a future version of LWC.
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/data_table_custom_types_styling

Comment: But I think then he'd have to implement a custom cell for EVERY data type (which might be ok if it's just text)

Comment: Hi both. It worked partially. I have added another question related to this. Any ideas: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/385739/lwc-lightning-datatable-highlight-cell-using-css-class