# LWC Lightning Datatable - Highlight Cell Using CSS Class

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable

I had a [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/385505/lwc-lightning-datatable-highlight-cell-dynamically) where I asked how to dynamically highlight a cell. This [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/data_table_custom_types_styling) provided some answers and I was able to highlight cells using *'slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture'*.

How do I do the same using a CSS Class. If I try plug in the class it does not work. Even some example from the link do not work. Only the one mentioned above:

```
const columns = [
    {
        label: 'EVENT REGISTRATION FIELD NAME', fieldName: 'eventregistrationfieldname', type: 'text',
        cellAttributes: {
            class: { fieldName: 'industryClass' },
        }
    },
    { label: 'SALESFORCE DATA', fieldName: 'salesforcedata', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'EVENT REGISTRATION DATA', fieldName: 'eventregistrationdata', type: 'text' }
];


registrationData.push({
                    ...,
                    'industryClass': eventRegData[key].isSelected ? 'slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture' : 'defaultText' //works
                    'industryClass': eventRegData[key].isSelected ? '.datatable-orange' : 'defaultText' //does not work. With/without period "."
                });



.datatable-orange {
color: #fff;
background-color: #e06000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) this is not yet supported.

> **Custom classes** are currently not supported. To apply custom styling on your datatable cells, create a custom data type and then apply your custom CSS classes.